# Understanding namespaced jQuery events, Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I understand how to trigger and listen for custom events. I can't figure out how Bootstrap is listening to custom events without triggering them.

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js#L32

Nowhere in their code can I find where they are triggering that custom scroll event. I took a look at the jQuery `on` docs and couldn't see if events are naturally namespaced somehow.

How does this work?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. I was baffled by this as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're listening to the scroll event which is a [naturally occurring event](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/). It's not a custom event, they've just namespaced it. The reason for namespacing it is so you can remove all events by just removing the namespace from all events. Look at [Using Namespaces in unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/).

Comment: Oh, I see. So by listening for 'scroll.*" it automatically just matches events of type "scroll". What if you triggered a custom event called "scroll.foo" but you were listening for "scroll.bar"?

Comment: I'm not sure, I have not tried that. But, yea. Listening for "scroll.bar" or "scroll.foo" will catch each trigger('scroll') and real scroll event. The namespace is mainly for easy/clean removal.

Comment: @kmiyashiro: Try this: `$(window).on('scroll.bar', function () { alert('scroll.bar') }).trigger('scroll.foo');` vs. `$(window).on('scroll.bar', function () { alert('scroll.bar') }).trigger('scroll.bar');` - the first alert won't show whereas the second one will.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. It seems like it's mostly for removing listeners rather than triggering them, though. I was initially thought it was used more for namespacing the triggered events themselves.